# Statistical test for only binary variables (dependent and indipendent) in r?

Tags: r, logistic, anova, binary-data

So i got a data set, where the depented variables as well as the predictors are binary. Now I'm a bit confused about what test i should use to examine which predictor has a significant influence to y. Below an example data set:

```
set.seed(556)
y <- data.frame(y = rbinom(8, 1, 0.6))
predictors <- expand.grid(list(x1 = c(0,1),
                x2 = c(0,1),
                x3 = c(0,1)))
df <- cbind(y, predictors)
df
  y x1 x2 x3
1 0  0  0  0
2 1  1  0  0
3 1  0  1  0
4 0  1  1  0
5 0  0  0  1
6 0  1  0  1
7 1  0  1  1
8 1  1  1  1
```

I'm pretty sure I should use a glm like this:

```
model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = "binomial", data = df)
```

However, I dont know how I get the results.

The easiest thing would be to do a `summary`, but my tutor says I should perform a typ II ANOVA using the car package like this:

```
library(car)
Anova(model)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
Response: y
   LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
x1    0.000  1      1.000
x2    2.093  1      0.148
x3    0.000  1      1.000
```

Using the `Anova` I don't know how to interpret the result, what I should report in the paper and I'm also not sure what test I used... is it an ANOVA, a Chi2-test?

Long story short: What test should I use with this dataset?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use summary() and the results reported there. What exactly you should report depends on the style that the journal uses, but many follow the APA style guide, which you can find online (or order a hard copy).  

I don't know why your tutor wants you to do an ANOVA like this. You could ask them.

Comment: @PeterFlom Would that ANOVA use a linear probability model?

Comment: @Dave  I believe that ANOVA is used to compare the variables. But I disagree with the tutor's advice. Maybe the OP can expand on why the tutor said what they said.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I had the same thoughts as you, but wasn't sure and didn't want to dicuss with my tutor. @PeterFlom I think the tutor's point is that the predictors could be seen as categorical variables and therefore an ANOVA would be the right thing. But reading your comments I think I will talk to him again about this analysis.

Comment: @Mil0 ANOVA isn't right for the main analysis because the dependent variable is categorical. But, inside R, you can use ANOVA for model comparison.

I strongly suspect that your tutor is simply in error. What are his qualifications? Is he a statistician or, at least, a student in a graduate program in statistics?

Comment: @PeterFlom My tutor is a Ph. D. supporting me with my bachelor-thesis in biology. He does know about the statistics he needs but isn't a statistician in the first place. Using ANOVA for model comparison does require two models (a Null-model and a full model) as input or am i wrong? I dont think that's what he want. Also, using the Anova() on this glm gives me chi2-values, so i suspect that's another test that gets performed.

Comment: I think you need to ask him.  

BTW, often, people who "know about the statistics they need" give bad advice to others about statistics. I'm not saying your tutor is doing this, but it happens  a lot.